# dynamic action name in playframework 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In route, how to use a dynamic action name, like {action} in 1.x. Is there any detail syntax statement for route file?

In 1.x, route will transfer a localhost/page/zzz?xxx=yyy to a action zzz with route

```
GET /{controller}/{action} {controller}.{action}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t do that at this level.
You can, however, write an invoker which will dynamically invoke an action using reflection…

```
GET  /:controller/:action     controllers.Invoker.invoke(controller, action)
```

With `invoke` looking like this:

```scala
object Invoker extends Controller {
  def invoke(controllerName: String, actionName: String) = Action { request =>
    // Retrieve the action using reflection and invoke it
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you retrieve the action with reflection?